# Перенос строки js-get-php-mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, get

Есть элемент textarea при чтении и отправке данных посредством get для сохранения в бд теряется символ переноса строки.

Фрагменты кода:
js

```
var message=$("#in_message").val();
$.get('chatpost.php?message='+message+);
```

php

```
$message=htmlspecialchars($_GET['message']);
$message=mysql_escape_string($message);
```

Символ переноса строки должен присутствовать в бд, а его нет. Возможно, это связано с `get` запросом, и стоить изменять строку у клиента, например `message = message.replace(/\n/g, '/n');`, но так тоже ничего не происходит.

Comment: А где, собственно, вопрос в вопросе?

Comment: Символ переноса строки должен присутствовать в бд а его нет, возможно это связано с get запросом и стоить изменять строку у клиента например  message = message.replace(/\n/g, '/n'); но так тоже ничего не происходит.

Comment: вот, это должно быть в вопросе.

Comment: а вы посмотрите входящее значение. как я понимаю get не должен передавать переносы строк. экранируйте их в js

Comment: Т.е. get - ом невозможно передать перенос строки, только Post ?

Comment: @Mike у меня ощущение, что да. он же делает строку. ни в какие <br> он их не переделывает

Comment: Странно, что replace не помогает